# Nesting a hyperlink in a table cell using jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

My HTML table has 5 columns, and I am using jinja to dynamically render the amount of columns depending on the amount of data. I would like to nest a hyperlink in the 5th column for every row.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from time import time as t
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/offers')
def offers():
    data = ( 
           ("user1","btc","ltc",t(),"127.0.0.1:5000/offer/abcd"),
           ("user2","xrp","xmr",t(),"127.0.0.1:5000/offer/efgh"),
           ("user3","bch","ltc",t(),"127.0.0.1:5000/offer/hijk")
           )
    return render_template("offers.html", data = data)
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <table class="GeneratedTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Have</th>
            <th>Want</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Link</Link></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in data %}
          <tr>
          {% for cell in row %}
            <td>{{cell}}
            </td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

This will create the table, however the links (127.0.0.1:5000/offers/xxxx) will not be hyperlinks. How do I only make the final column a hyperlink using the links provided by the dataset? thanks.

Comment: you can change the data itself by adding a tag to the ;link . `<a href="127.0.0.1:5000/offer/abcd">127.0.0.1:5000/offer/abcd</a>`  and so on then use it in jinja with safe filter. {{cell|safe}}

Answer (score 3):

Jinja does not recognise URL by default. You still need to manually format it. There are 2 ways to do that.

1. You can prepare the data in HTML format such as

```
data = ( 
       ("user1","btc","ltc",t(),"<a href=xxx>127.0.0.1:5000/offer/abcd</a>"),
       ("user2","xrp","xmr",t(),"127.0.0.1:5000/offer/efgh"),
       ("user3","bch","ltc",t(),"127.0.0.1:5000/offer/hijk")
       )
```

2. Or you can format it in jinja template as below:

   ```
    <tbody>
      {% for row in data %}
      <tr>

          {% for cell in row %}
          <td>

              {% if loop.index0 != 4 %}
                  {{cell}}
              {% else %}
                  <a href={{ cell }}>{{ cell }}</a>
              {% endif %}

          </td>
          {% endfor %}

      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
   ```

   Here the key is to use Jinja syntax `loop.index0` to get the index number of `row`.